# Complexity of a triple for loop

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

```
for(I = 0; I < n; I++)
 for(j = I; j < n; j++)
  for(k = I; k < n; k++)
   statement;
```

outer loop runs n times.
2nd loop runs (n - I) times = n(n-1)/2 times.
3rd loop runs (n- I) times = n(n-1)/2 times.
so statement will run (n(n-1)/2)^2 times.
Is this correct?

Comment: This fragment is incorrect: "(n - I) times = n(n-1)/2 times". Try to express it in a way that is mathematically correct; this might help.

Comment: "will run (n(n-1)/2)^2 times. Is this correct?" It doesn't look correct.  n((n-1)/2)^2 is closer.  Because a triple loop is O(n^3)

Answer (score 2):

You can count like this to check whether it is right or not

```
int Cnt = 1; // initialization
for(I = 0; I < n; I++)
 for(j = I; j < n; j++)
  for(k = I; k < n; k++, Cnt++)
   printf ("This is the %dth time\n", Cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n^3) - because

```
O(n^3+AnyConst*n^2+AnyOtherConst*n+ThirdConst)=O(n^3)
```

O notation estimates asymptotic behavior as n goes to infinity, therefore, only fastest growing component matters.